# Circumventing input-to-action latency in mpl's plt.draw() function

Tags: python, performance, user-interface, matplotlib

In trying to track down the source of an unacceptable (`257ms`) runtime of matplotlib's plt.draw() function, I stumbled upon this article:  http://bastibe.de/2013-05-30-speeding-up-matplotlib.html.  In particular, this quote caught my eye:

> "I am using pause() here to update the plot without blocking. The correct way to do this is to use draw() instead..."

Digging further, I found that `plt.draw()` can be substituted by two commands,

```
plt.pause(0.001)
fig.canvas.blit(ax1.bbox)
```

Which take up `256ms` and `1ms` respectively in my code.

This was abnormal, why would a `1ms` pause take `256ms` to complete?  I took some data, and found the following:

```
plt.pause(n):
  n(s)           time(ms)       overhead(n(ms)-time(ms))
 0.0001          270-246         ~246ms
 0.001           270-254         ~253ms
 0.01            280-265         ~255ms
 0.1             398-354         ~254ms
 0.2             470-451         ~251ms
 0.5             779-759         ~259ms
 1.0            1284-1250        ~250ms
numbers courtesy of rkern's line_profiler
```

This makes it very clear that `plt.pause()` is doing more than just pausing the program, and I was correct:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   175                                           def pause(interval):
   176                                               """
   177                                               Pause for *interval* seconds.
   178                                           
   179                                               If there is an active figure it will be updated and displayed,
   180                                               and the GUI event loop will run during the pause.
   181                                           
   182                                               If there is no active figure, or if a non-interactive backend
   183                                               is in use, this executes time.sleep(interval).
   184                                           
   185                                               This can be used for crude animation. For more complex
   186                                               animation, see :mod:`matplotlib.animation`.
   187                                           
   188                                               This function is experimental; its behavior may be changed
   189                                               or extended in a future release.
   190                                           
   191                                               """
   192         1            6      6.0      0.0      backend = rcParams['backend']
   193         1            1      1.0      0.0      if backend in _interactive_bk:
   194         1            5      5.0      0.0          figManager = _pylab_helpers.Gcf.get_active()
   195         1            0      0.0      0.0          if figManager is not None:
   196         1            2      2.0      0.0              canvas = figManager.canvas
   197         1       257223 257223.0     20.4              canvas.draw()
   198         1          145    145.0      0.0              show(block=False)
   199         1      1000459 1000459.0     79.5              canvas.start_event_loop(interval)
   200         1            2      2.0      0.0              return
   201                                           
   202                                               # No on-screen figure is active, so sleep() is all we need.
   203                                               import time
   204                                               time.sleep(interval)
once again courtesy of rkern's line_profiler
```

This was a breakthrough, as it was suddenly clear why `plt.pause()` was able to replace `plt.draw()`, it had a draw function inside it with that same ~`250ms` overhead I was getting at the start of my program.

At this point, I decided to profile `plt.draw()` itself:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   551                                           def draw():
   571         1       267174 267174.0    100.0      get_current_fig_manager().canvas.draw()
```

Alright, one more step down the rabbit hole:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    57                                               def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
    58       769         1798      2.3      0.7          before(artist, renderer)
    59       769       242060    314.8     98.5          draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    60       769         1886      2.5      0.8          after(artist, renderer)
```

Unfortunately, this was the point at which my ability to run my profiler through the source code ended, leaving me scratching my head at this next level of `draw()` function, and why it was being called 769 times.

It turns out, the answer was right in front of me the whole time!  That same article, which started this whole obsessive hunt in the first place, was actually created to study the same strange behavior!  Their solution:  To replace `plt.draw()` with individual calls to each `artist` which needed to be updated, rather than every single one!

I hope my chasing of this behavior can help others understand it, though currently I'm stuck with a `CGContextRef is NULL` error whenever I try to replicate his methods, which seems to be specific to the `MacOSX` backend...

More info as it comes!  Please add any more relevant information in answers below, or if you can help me with my `CGContextRef is NULL` error.

Comment: This is of interest to a lot of people, but liable to be closed as it reads a little more like a blog than Q&A. I think with a little tweak it could be better - maybe split it into a question and self answer, or make the question but at the end a little more concise and precise.